# How to backup/restore a JIRA project configuration

Tags: jira

is there a way to backup a JIRA project configuration and then restore?

The issue I have is that sometimes doing workflows changes I can break the whole configuration.
So, I'm looking for a way to easily rollback to the previous working version of the project configuration.
Please note that I cannot rollback the whole JIRA server as it will affect other projects.
We are using the latest version of the Jira Service Desk on premises.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, see full answer [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/How-to-make-full-backup-of-single-project-in-Jira/qaq-p/363325).

> You can't.
>
> JIRA does a full export of everything, and you can import
>   the issues from one project from that.  But that's it. If you need
>   single project backups with configuration, you'll need extra
>   functionality.  This is exactly the case where I would reach for
>   Botron's tool -
>   https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.botronsoft.jira.configurationmanager

Comment: It seems like the tool is mainly focusing on migrating a project to another server while I'm looking for a way to roll back to a previous stable configuration on the same project/server.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you publish a change to a workflow, JIRA asks you if it has to save a copy of the original. If you do that, it should be easy to revert to a previous version. Still it gets cumbersome to manage lots of copies of a workflow and to understand what changed when.

If you want a bit more control, you can also export your workflow to xml and keep that somewhere. If you need to rollback, you can import from that xml again. For more details see the [documentation here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/sharing-your-workflow-861253581.html).

If you want even more control, then add-ons like [Botron's configuration manager](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.botronsoft.jira.configurationmanager/server/overview) can indeed be useful.